# Collaboratively edited flowcharts?

Tags: webapp-rec

Interested in an online app that allows multiple users to edit, perhaps simultaneously, a flowchart or collection of flowcharts.

So far I've only found sites which allow you to share your flowcharts with others.

In this case free is required, and it's ok if the flowcharts are public.  To some degree, I'd like to see a stackexchange or wiki like site, except the posts are community editable flowcharts.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [LucidChart](https://www.lucidchart.com). It let's you collaborate in real-time too.

Answer (score 1):

There are many sites for creating flowcharts, and many have collaborative features. E.g:

- http://www.lovelycharts.com
- http://creately.com/

You can also look at the various mind-mapping tools. Google docs has nice collaborative features, and it has some ability for creating diagrams. If you really want a wiki, MediaWiki (the open-source script behind wikipedia) also has some sort of charting ability.